# Google Assistant Default Numbers

Tags: google-assistant

Whenever I ask Google Assistant to send a text to a contact with multiple numbers, it asks me which number to send to. Is there a way to set a default number to use when sending a text message? I know I can set default numbers in my address book, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Thanks for any suggestions!